# Online project management services

Tags: webapp-rec, tasks, project-management

I need a user-friendly and cleverly designed web service to manage my projects and tasks. No matter if it's a free or paid service. Having a comment system and some game mechanics would be a big plus.

1 service per answer please (to be able to see which one receives most votes).

Comment: Game Mechanics: You mean focused towards game development?

Comment: @Noctrine: No. I mean game mechanics as being used on Stackexchange sites (votes, badges, etc.).

Comment: Wow!  Good question.  I had no idea there were this many project management tools available.

Comment: @Michelle - A total list of Agile/Scrum/Kanban tools can be found here: http://agilescout.com/best-agile-scrum-tools/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[BaseCamp](http://basecamphq.com/)**

By 37Signals, the company of Ruby-On-Rails inventor David Heinemeier Hansson.

Comment: I have had experience with Basecamp as well and it is very good and easy to use.  It also inexpensive.

Answer (score 12):

[**FogBugz**](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/)

It is intended as software bug tracker and project management but works for just about any use.

It is free for one or two person teams. For more users it is $25 a month.

Comment: I use fogbugz and LOVE it. I hate the time tracking system though.

Comment: I use it for all my projects, it is great! I don't mind the time tracking, it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 8):

### [Trello](https://trello.com/landing)

Trello is used for all kinds of project and task management. It’s based on a simple board and card metaphor.

Trello supports Chrome 9 and above, Firefox 4 and above, Safari 5.0.5 and above, and Internet Explorer 9 and above.

Trello blog is [here](http://blog.trello.com/).

Answer (score 6):

[CodeBase](http://www.codebasehq.com/)

> Codebase is your software project management tool with fast, reliable Git, Mercurial & Subversion hosting baked right it.

Comment: I've been using Codebase for a few months, and I really love it. It lets you have as many repos as you want linked to any project (and it's still considered 1 project), it's pretty affordable, and it's got a great UI. I'd +10 if I could.

Answer (score 5):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) if you don't mind self-hosting

Comment: easy to use & free!!!

Comment: http://plan.io offers a hosted version. Redmine kicks ass!

Comment: What does "self-hosting" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

[LiquidPlanner](http://www.liquidplanner.com/) seems quite good. It has a nice feature that shows the spread of task completion times based on past performance.

The again there is always [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) ;-)

Neither are free, although FogBugz does have various free for academic use options.

Comment: FogBugz is completely free for up to two users.  I actually used to use it as my personal organizer for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

[Agile Zen](http://www.agilezen.com) is one of my favorites.  Very simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

### [Wedoist](http://wedoist.com/)

> Wedoist is a project manager that has
>   status updates, a task manager and a
>   comment system. It also uses game
>   mechanics to increase productivity and
>   usage.
>
> Wedoist should be a lot more dynamic
>   than most other applications as most
>   of it is rendered in JavaScript and
>   Comet is used for realtime updates.
>   The future plan is to make the
>   realtime aspect more central (such as
>   adding a group chat).

Answer (score 0):

### [Thymer](http://thymer.com/)

Project management and task planning for people who hate project management and task planning.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ProjectManager](http://projectmanager.com). I have used it for a few projects and like it.

Answer (score 0):

We're using [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) in the company I run. They provide unlimited code hosting (Git/SVN), ticketing, wiki, scrum and other useful tools, and doesn't cost much.

Answer (score 0):

We use Gemini at my work.  Mostly for bug tracking, but it's was created for Project Management.
http://www.countersoft.com

Answer (score 0):

**Zoho Projects**
I've used [Zoho Projects](http://projects.zoho.com/home.na) briefly and, like most Zoho stuff, it offers a lot of options, but isn't the most polished of experiences :)

Answer (score 0):

## [AgileZen](http://agilezen.com)

It's simple and it is lean, and gaining traction from what I see around the interwebs. It is written and run by Nate Kohari, a name many people in especially the .Net community will recognize (Ninject comest to mind).

The authors themselves write:

> AgileZen is a simple and flexible application that draws on ideas from lean manufacturing to provide a new way of thinking about project management. Rather than organizing tasks into a bunch of lists and trying to slice and dice your way through it, AgileZen lets you see and interact with your work visually.

Answer (score 0):

## [Paymo](http://paymo.biz)

I personally use this for the time registration and invoicing.

Invoicing your clients based on time registration is super easy.

Also comes with a free iPhone app.

[image: http://www.paymo.biz/wp-content/themes/paymo/images/paymo_screenshot.jpg]
<sub>(source: [paymo.biz](http://www.paymo.biz/wp-content/themes/paymo/images/paymo_screenshot.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Bright Green Projects is very new to the project management market.  Their UI is pretty amazing .. nice simple, clean app for both agile and waterfall implementations.

Check 'em out: http://www.brightgreenprojects.com

Answer (score 0):

We use [PoP Project](http://www.mypopproject.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Teambox](http://teambox.com) is not bad either. Email-centric too. :) You could self-host it or use their hosted solution. It has a calendar and Gantt charts. No game mechanics though :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to plan using Gantt diagram like in MS Project, [try this: SpiderPlan](http://www.spider-plan.com)

Answer (score 0):

[TeamWorkPM](http://www.teamworkpm.net/) is good. I have not tried it, but I hear from my friends.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using PivotalTracker.com and am quite happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

### [Freedcamp](http://Freedcamp.com)

It's like an alternative to basecamp, and offers importing from basecamp

Answer (score 0):

### [**Deskaway**](http://www.deskaway.com)

offers a simple web interface and is quite rich on features.

Answer (score 0):

If you need project management tool, that can handle the financial part of the project then take a look on Timelog Project: [www.timelog.com](http://www.timelog.com).

It does timeregistration, invoicing and reporting in on package.

Answer (score 0):

**[Done Done](http://www.getdonedone.com/)**

Been looking for some bug tracking software for ages and came across this. It's actually really nice to use and looks friendly unlike the majority of the others. Having used everything from Bugzilla to 16bugs it's a joy to use.

Also their pricing plan is based on the amount of users NOT the amount of projects like most others. We have a small team but lot's of projects so it started becoming very expensive with other tracking software.

**The amount of projects are unlimited for ALL packages, even the free package which has up to 3 users!**

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Enbraun's eResource Scheduler.

It is an efficient resource planning, scheduling and management software which lets people to schedule resource effectively. The software has nice reporting features, time sheet management, drag & drop scheduling which adds a lot to its list of features. There is a trial period if you're wanting to see what it's like.

eResource Scheduler  is  a collaborative and configurable resource scheduling, planning and management software. Drag & drop scheduling, time-sheet, utilization and forecasting reports and more.