# Project management for marketing group

Tags: project-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online project management services](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/723/online-project-management-services)

I work in the marketing group of my firm and I'm looking for a prodject management tool that we can use.

We have a lot of small prodjects during the year. Some of these can be to make lots of posters, t-shirts, movies and so on. We are a totale of 6 people in the team and right now we are just emailing the prodjects back and fort. Some problems occure and information is lost. So im looking for a prodject management tool we can use.

It needs to be self hosted or at least on the web. I have can set it up myself but it will be slow. It needs to be simple and nice in design. It needs to be able to have a "due date" it needs to keep track of all our prodjects where there can come more information at different times that needs to be updated many times. It would be nice if its easy to use.

I have looket at some and many of the mare very software development oriented so they feel a little massive.

Comment: Duplicate of [Online project management services](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/723/online-project-management-services).

Answer (score 0):

if you're happy to shell out for paid solution, have you considered base camp?

http://basecamphq.com/

They also offer a free trial, so it wouldnt hurt to have look

Comment: Its a little too big and i feel its really software oriented. I just tried it and its not really what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [TeamLab](http://teamlab.com/) for a team of similar size and finding it does all that we need without complicating things. It has both project management and other collaborative tools.

And it's free...

Answer (score 0):

[Manymoon](https://www.manymoon.com/auth/login) is another free one that might be worth a look as it has good scheduling and projct management functionality without the steep learning curve a lot of PM software requires.  And it integrates with Google calendar.