# Free project management apps?

Tags: project-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online project management services](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/723/online-project-management-services)

What are some free project management apps? I'm looking for something quite minimal for a small web development team. We're looking for something between a complex todo list and a minimal project management app. We don't want to get a paid app yet as we don't know if we're really going to use it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly recommend [Redmine](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine). I have seen it in action inside a team and is definitely efficient. And free.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of this one. Btw, why don't you point the link to the official page (http://www.redmine.org/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bitnami contributor and tend to have those links more handy. Besides I myself use these installers instead of the original products, for ease of use. A matter of answering too fast, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) is free and fits the "quite minimal" definition, it's simple but it just works.
It's an agile, iterative workflow and story management. I love the concept of "velocity" that helps you plan future iterations.