# Development Team: Web app to log activities

Tags: webapp-rec

Can anyone recommend a good web app (that we can host ourselves), to help my team track their daily activities?

I've been using Tracks, personally, and found it to be great to keep on top of work-in-progress and see where my time is going but I need this on a team level.

I'd like to be to see what activities the team are working on, where time is being spent/lost and where the time sinks are.

Ideally this would be open source/free if possible.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/723/online-project-management-services here you can find many answers related to ur query

Comment: Thank you, but the only one I could see that was free was Redmine, although that does look pretty good.

Comment: Self-hosted web apps are off-topic here. Recommendation questions are not welcome either. Please read the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the answers there, I would like to add the following:

1. [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is an open source, web-based project management and bug-tracking tool. Trac allows hyperlinking information between a computer bug database, revision control and wiki content. It also serves as a web interface to a version control system like Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs.
2. [Project HQ](http://projecthq.org/) is a collaborative open source project management tool, similar to Basecamp and activeCollab. Project HQ is built on open source technologies like Python, Pylons and SQLAlchemy and is fully database independent. Project HQ uses a structured workflow to assist you in managing your projects.
3. [Opengoo](http://www.opengoo.org/) is a complete online solution focused on improving productivity, collaboration, communication and management of your teams. OpenGoo main features include document management, contact management, e-mail, project management, and time management. Text documents and presentations can be created and edited online. Files can be uploaded, organized and shared, independent of file formats.
4. [ClockingIT](http://wiki.clockingit.com/) is a free Project Management solution, which helps your team stay focused and on top of things.
5. [KForge](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kforge) is an open-source (GPL) system for managing software and knowledge projects. It re-uses existing best-of-breed tools such as a versioned storage (subversion), a tracker (trac), and wiki (trac or moinmoin), integrating them with the system’s own facilities (projects, users, permissions etc). KForge also provides a complete web interface for project administration as well a fully-developed plugin system so that new services and features can be easily added.

The above are all **open-source** solutions.

Comment: Thanks, the ClockingIT looks promising. I will try this out.